# Youmax code for weebly website

Tags: youtube, embed, weebly

Situation Summary:
My name is Thomas Flint and I run a small youtube channel for a while now. I like to improve my "professional" look, so I made a weebly site. Since I have my site, I posted my video's on there 1 by 1.

Today I found Youmax, a code where you can make a embed player for you youtube uploads. [Youmax website](http://www.codehandling.com/2013/03/youmax-20-complete-youtube-channel-on.html)

I Tried the whole evening to get youmax on my weebly site, but without success.
I can't get the code working. Also I have no good idea what I am doing with coding.

Question:
Can somebody give me a very simple tutorial on how I get my youtube channel on my weebly website with youmax.

Thanks in advance,

Thomas Flint

Comment: Please share a link to your website where you are having issues with Youmax. We can have a look at the errors then :)

Comment: here is the link: http://digitallockprod.weebly.com/thomasflint.html All my video's are stil under it, but I put the code above it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload the Youmax script to some server (Google Drive for example) and then add a link to it on your page.

So as of right now, you have the below script linked into your HTML page -

```
<script src="./youmax.js"></script>
```

which points to http://digitallockprod.weebly.com/youmax.js which will give you a 404 does not exist error.

You can follow the below tutorial (Step 3 onwards) to host your youmax.js file in Google Drive. Then replace your Google Drive link in place of "*./youmax.js*"

http://www.mybloggerlab.com/2013/04/how-to-host-css-or-javascript-files-in-blogger-using-google-drive.html

Also I would recommend using the latest version [Youmax 8.0](http://codecanyon.net/item/youmax-youtube-channel-on-your-website/9989505) for more features and better performance :)

Answer (score 0):

Upload the youmax.js file to Weebly. To do this go to the "Design" tab and click "Edit HTML/CSS". Add youmax.js under "ASSETS". Save and name your theme then you can access the file by using:

```
<script src="files/theme/youmax.js"></script>
```

With this approach if you ever decide to change your theme then you'll need to add the file again and save it as a custom theme.